# ImageView Rotation with different pivot

Tags: android, android-imageview

I'd like to rotate an ImageView with a different pivot in Android Studio.

This is how it rotates when it's -45 degree by default pivot(centre).

[image]

So, when we do animation, it works in a fixed image area such as a fan or a windmill.

But what I want to do is like this.

[image]

The red point is the new pivot that I want. In this way, it will take over 4 times bigger areas if it rotates 360 degrees.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Not a formal answer, but conceptually something which might work would be enlarge the current image such that your desired pivot becomes the new center.  Then, rotate using the current API, and then reduce afterward, to rescale to the original size.

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/31007689/7261183